# MotionEvent ACTION_MOVE still firing after dragging outside original view bounds

Tags: android

I have 3 Imageview in relativelayout and i have added onTouchListener for all ImageView

Now when i press my finger on any imageview onTouchListener is fired, which is working correctly, also when i move finger arround without lifting up ACTION_MOVE touch is fired, everything works correctly.

However when i take my finger outside the imageview ACTION_MOVE is still fired :(

i don't want ACTION_MOVE when finger goes outside the ImageView, on the other hand if my finger goes to some other ImageView, ACTION_MOVE touch should be fired from that ImageView as TouchListener is added for all ImageView

Comment: Its by design that it continues to report outside of the original view area. Can you just manually filter the events by their location once you receive them?

Comment: Yes, i can manually filter event by getting location X, Y. but the problem is i donot receive the event ACTION_MOVE from other ImageView since it continues to fir the ACTION_MOVE from original ImageView only :(

Answer (score 2):

You should stop responding to ACTION_MOVE after you receive an ACTION_CANCEL or ACTION_OUTSIDE MotionEvent.  The ACTION_OUTSIDE is fired when the user moves their finger outside of the view's bounds.  The ACTION_CANCEL is also fired and in addition covers the case when a parent ViewGroup steals touch events.

Mainly, treat ACTION_CANCEL like ACTION_UP and you will be good to go.